# Configure Client Certificate for soap in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, soap

I'm consuming a Soap Webservice with authenticationMode="MutualCertificate". Localy everything works fine because the certificate are stored in my local machine. Now I want to deploy the project in Azure. I'm stack on how to install and retrieve certificates from Azure. My local configuration are:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="TestSoapBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="true" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
      </security>

      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>

        <clientCertificate findValue="xxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />

        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          <defaultCertificate findValue="xxxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />

        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to follow the steps below:

1 - Import the certificates to Key Vault in Azure following this sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate

2 - You could use python to retrieve the certificate from the specific Azure Key Vault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/quick-create-python

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the public certificate is .cer I can't import in azure .cer?

Comment: Yes, you can add .cer files. You just need to put a name and upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue importing the certificates in Azure portal. For the Private Certificate: in App Service --> T**LS/SSL settings**-->**Private Key Certificates(.pfx)**--> **Upload Certificate**.
For the Public Certificate: App Service --> **TLS/SSL settings**-->**Public Key Certificates(.pfx)**-->Upload Certificate.

In App Service Configuration-> Add New Application Setting-> Name: **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** and **Value**: *

In the web.config set storeLocation="CurrentUser" and storeName="My"

```
<clientCredentials>

        <clientCertificate findValue="xxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />

        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          <defaultCertificate findValue="xxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />

        </serviceCertificate>
```